# Python proxy: how to forward traffic from sockets efficently?

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I am trying to create very simple http proxy using python.
Using http library I created handler for CONNECT method. when I got address to which I need forward traffic from client I met with the issue.
How do I make my server act as a bridge between client and host?
I've tried basic recv and send but it took a lot time for recv. I tried using non-blocking sockets in a loop but it worked poorly.
**What is the right way to forward traffic using sockets in my case**?
Here is my code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socket

local_port = 8080

class ProxyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_CONNECT(self):
        ip, port = self.path.split(":")
        out_connection = socket.socket()
        out_connection.connect((ip, int(port)))
        #Send data between connections

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ProxyHost = HTTPServer(("", local_port), ProxyServer)
    try:
        ProxyHost.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ProxyHost.server_close()
```

PS: I am planning to modify traffic sent between client and the host